# Check if a path/folder is available

Tags: vba

Using VBA at Excel, I save data of a table at a ".dat" file, at a network folder.
How can check if the folder is available?
My idea would be if folder A is not available, save the file at folder B
Something like

```
if {{ "\\PC2\Shared" is not available }} then then nA = "D:\data.dat" else nA = "\\PC2\Shared\data.dat"
```

Comment: The best way to handle this is just try to write the file, and handle the error if it fails

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FileSystemObject` to check if a folder exists.

```
Const FolderA As String = "\\Some path"
Const FolderB As String = "\\Some path"

Dim folderPath As String

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If .FolderExists(FolderA) Then folderPath = FolderA Else folderPath = FolderB
End With

'use folderPath to append the file name and save
```

Comment: Does `FolderExists` return True even if the user does not have Write permissions? Is there a way to check if the user has write permissions?

Comment: You can use `Dim fso = new FileSystemObject()`  for seeing for methods are available if you add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting` in the project references. This was you can see what the parameters of `fso.FolderExists()` as well as all the other methods defined in this library.

Comment: @Toddleson I don't really know to be honest. I suspect if you have read permission you should be able to see the folder so it will return true, but writing into it is different, if you don't have permission it will throw an error. As far as I know, FSO does not have a method to check for write access, usually you try to create a file/folder and catch the error if any.